# Why does BufferBlock<T>.ReceiveAsync() hang when data is available?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am new to TPL Dataflow.

I am trying to build a throttled async update to a fairly fast flowing input stream. BufferBlock seemed a nice match for this with the idea that I could call the ReceiveAll() to grab everything off the buffer and on the occasions there is nothing there I can await on a ReceiveAsync() to pick up the next element as it arrives.

But it seems to sometimes hang on the ReceiveAsync() call; and the conditions of failure are odd.

**Please note** I am interested in why this hangs. I have already found another way to make the application I am working on work, but it is possibly not as neat or extensible as I am not using TPL Dataflow since I obviously don't understand how it works.

**Further note** The key usage here is that I do a *TryReceiveAll()* then *await ReceiveAsync()* if that fails. This is a common pattern where burst data arrives and I want to process data so far as a batch. Which is the reason that I don't want to just loop on the *ReceiveAsync()*, and thus why just directly hooking an *ActionBlock* or a *TransformBlock* would not work. If I remove the *TryReceiveAll()* my version seems to work as expected; though, as other comments have noted the behaviour, seems to be different for different people so this may be a coincidence.

Here is a failing example... drop it in a console app with *System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll* referenced and usings:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
```

Failing example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = context.Token });
        var task = Task.Run(() =>ProcessBuffer(buffer, context.Token), context.Token);

        // shove 10 things onto the buffer
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // shove something on the buffer every second
            buffer.Post(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        context.Cancel();
    }

    // 1. We expect to see something hit the buffer and go immediately through on the TryReceiveAll
    // 2. Then we should see nothing for a second
    // 3. Then we immediately process the next element from the await ReceiveAsync.
    // 4. We should then repeat 2 & 3 'till i == 10 as there will be nothign for TryReceiveAll.
    static async Task ProcessBuffer(BufferBlock<int> buffer, CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": This Breaks it...");
                IList<int> elements;
                if (!buffer.TryReceiveAll(out elements))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var element = await buffer.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), token);
                        elements = new List<int> { element };
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException) { Console.WriteLine("Failed to get anything on await..."); }
                }
                if (elements != null) Console.WriteLine("Elements: " + string.Join(", ", elements));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Exception in thread: " + e.ToString()); }
    }
}
```

output is:

```
11:27: This Breaks it...
Elements: 0
11:27: This Breaks it...
Failed to get anything on await...
11:27: This Breaks it...
Elements: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

...And so on

But if I change the log line

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": This Breaks it...");
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("This Works...");
```

The the output comes out as expected:

```
This Works...
Elements: 0
This Works...
Elements: 1
This Works...
Elements: 2
This Works...
```

etc.
But even the act of copying text from the console will switch it back to the failing output.

Ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You could remove `ProcessBuffer` and simply link the `BufferBlock` to an `ActionBlock` or `TransformBlock`.

Comment: Well the question is why does this seem to hang; which I am interested in even if there is another way to achieve the system goal that lies behind this.
The above code is a sample to reproduce the issue. It has nothing to do  with the real system I am building.
As to what I am doing; I've got a inbound flow of data that I am caching and signalling new data on over the buffer. I have a separate task that will then periodically lift all updates and push them out through several client streams.

Comment: Maybe someone who is an expert with the Dataflow API could explain this, but it looks to me like a straight-up bug, and an odd one at that. It is the formatting _and_ printing of the `DateTime` value that causes the issue. You can retrieve `DateTime.Now` without causing the issue, and you can print to the console text of the exact same length. To further confuse the question, I have found that _sometimes_ it still works fine, and that if I either don't format the `DateTime` value or don't print it, it also works fine.

Comment: I suspect someone implementing the `BufferBlock` object or a related class was trying to be clever, attempted to write a fancy synchronization implementation (e.g. lockless, spin-wait, etc.) and introduced a race condition that breaks the wait in certain cases. For what it's worth, if I flip the threads by calling `ProcessBuffer()` directly and running the `Post()` loop in a `Task.Run()`, I am unable to reproduce the problem at all.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce with v 4.5.24 of Tpl.Dataflow and a straight copy & paste into a .NET4.6.1 console app. Any chance you can post a complete example somewhere?

Comment: scratch that; sorry, reproduced now. It's v intermittant for me and never happens with the debugger attached (at least not so far)